# How can I get a DB's service name when I have the hostname, port number and SID?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am attempting to add a public DB link to an existing DB in Oracle SQL Developer.

I have the following window:

[image: Create Database Link Window]

Is there any way of determining the service name if I have the hostname, port number and SID of the DB I'd like to create a link of?

Comment: Maybe this question is more applicable for https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you might not be able to - to get a list of available services, you need access to the operating system so you can interact with the Oracle Listener - if you're in the database, you can use SQL to get the service name